# How to find sequence of numbers from 0-9 in a binary file?

Tags: binary-analysis

I'd like to find a sequence of values in a 32MB data stream, where the values are all between 0x00 and 0x09 and there are about 20-40 of them in a row.

Maybe this can be done with Hex Workshop, but i have no clue how...

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to write a quick python script to do this.

with a few lines of code you should be able to break the binary down (complete or just a section) into an array of bytes and then look through and the array and compare each to see if it falls into your sequence.

Check out this library below.

https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile

Comment: What is the connection between pefile and the problem at hand? Additionally, if you could provide an example python script, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

grep can do what you ask for

```
:\>f:\usr\bin\ls -lag foo.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 33554432 Sep  9 13:31 foo.bin

:\>f:\usr\bin\grep  -obUaP "\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39" foo.bin
96:0123456789
336:0123456789
832:0123456789
1472:0123456789
2144:0123456789
3328:0123456789
25895568:0123456789
25895579:0123456789
25895590:0123456789
25895601:0123456789
25895612:0123456789

:\>
```

Comment: Here is the explaination about `-obUaP`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17168847/4406921